# Nuget problems with Azure Function 1.x and VS17

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-functions

I'm having some problems with my project, I don't know where it went wrong exactly but now my Azure Function 1.x project won't build. It's critical I get it building again :-/.

This is a .NET Framework 4.6.2 project with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.35 (latest before 2.x).

I've got a couple of usings that it does not seem to able to find, and Function itself has this error:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'FunctionNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So my [FunctionName] has red squiggly lines and I don't understand why, it should be in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions? I've tried to clean and rebuild the project.

I've tried to reinstall my packages by command `Update-Package -reinstall -Project MyVeryCriticalProject`

```
PM> Update-Package -reinstall -Project MyVeryCriticalProject
No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'MyVeryCriticalProject'.
Executing nuget actions took 0 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:10.4211309
```

It also complains about missing namespace:

[image]

But my csproj file has these included as I have installed them in nuget:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.35" />
```

I have VS2019 installed and I am going to move this project over to Azure Functions 3.x and .NET Core but right now I need this to compile :-/ Any clue?

Edit: with VS17 I've just a new Function 1.x project and right from the get-go its missing stuff:

[image]

I have .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed, and just reinstalled it.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with package construction. Only install the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package is enough. This package comes with many components.

Comment: Hi,does my answer help you handle your issue or did you have any other concern about this?

Comment: Or if you already have  a workaround, you can share with us here. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to just install the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package. From your error message, the problem lies with the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package. It seems that the build of the software package has failed. Please make sure you are using the latest version of the nuget package management tool.

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget problems with Azure Function 1.x and VS17

I think there are something broken in your VS2017 environment.

And in my side, when I created **Azure Function** project with `Azure Function v1`, it works well without any build errors. So l suggest you could try these suggestions:

**Note**: `Update-Package -reinstall -Project MyVeryCriticalProject` does not support **PackageReference** nuget format.

**1)** make sure that VS2017 has installed Azure development workload with those option tools( on the right part).

[image]

**2)** change your itemgroup xml node and keep the unique nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` and delete the others which are the dependencies of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`. Like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.35" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then try to uninstall `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` nuget package under Nuget Package Management UI and then reinstall it.

**3)** Then click `Restore Nuget Packages` by Right-click on your solution

**4)** disable any third party extensions under `Tools`-->`Updates and Extensions` in case some extensions causes this behavior. From your code editor, I found you used some extensions like Resharper.

**5)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder(a hidden folder which is in the same directory as the `xxx.sln`), `bin` ,`obj` folder and then restart your project again.

**6)** [repair VS in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

**In addition**, you could try to create a new Azure Function in VS2017 to test whether it is the problem of your own current project.